# NSCollectionView error: Parameter indexPath out of bounds or nil

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

I've recently been playing around with OSX programming (usually an iOS guy) but I've hit a strange issue with NSCollectionView that I just can't seem to debug.

When I change the data that my data source uses to populate the collection with items, I call `reloadData()` on the collection view as usual and sometimes hits an assertion. The error I get is `Parameter indexPath out of bounds or nil`. If I don't change the data the app always crashes at the same point(s) though sometimes, usually the first time, it works just fine and only crashes subsequently.

Now, I've debugged this numerous times. The data is correct and at no point in *my* code do I ever see a nil index path. The assertion always occurs on the `makeItemWithIdentifier` call, and always on the last item in the collection. If I continue, I either see what I expect or else some of the cells from the previous collection are still there behind the new cells.

At one point I refactored the code slightly and found the error occurring in `NSCollectionView`s `itemAtIndexPath:` function instead.

Has anyone else seen this error and, if so, what caused it?

**Update 2:** I now know what is causing this issue, but have no idea how to prevent it. What happens is this: the user clicks an item in the collection view. That item changes the data object that the data source is reading from calls `reloadData` during the collection view delegate's `didSelectItemsAtIndexPaths` method. For some reason, after execution of this method, the collection view is queried again for the cell with that index path. If the table has been reloaded in the meantime then that cell is gone, leading to the exception. In short: you can't call 'reload' on a collection view while a mouse event is being processed on one of its cells without getting an annoying assertion. So if anyone can think of a way around this issue, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Can you post code about your dataSource change, and code around makeItemWithIdentifier?

Comment: Not much point, it's all standard stuff. To clarify though, I don't actually change the data source itself, only the data it's using to populate the table view.

Comment: When did you change the data? When did you `reloadData`? As a quick check, I do both inside `didSelectItemsAtIndexPaths`, it works. However, I don't think this is a good practice.

Comment: I suspect you are adding a new indexPath, while the data object remains the same. That's how I could force the error to happen.

Comment: Sorry Harry but no, it appears more like the opposite - I have fewer index paths than the collection view thinks I should have. I can't say I'm convinced that this ought to be a bad practice either. One of the commonest things you might want to do is removing or changing the content of a collection view in response to someone interacting with it.

Comment: So I think you have found the problem. You should make sure the number of items and the indexPath are the same.

Comment: Uh, that's not possible. The only control I have over the index paths is by returning how many sections / rows there are in the collection view. In all situations this is returning the correct value. The problem is that you cannot change the content of a collection view within its didSelect method without risking an assertion error.

Comment: You'd better post your code, since it works for me!!